# Fonts folder location on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying install fontconfig on Windows Phone 8.1 and I need to get a location of the fonts on the windows phone.

I am using freetype to render text but I would like to use system fonts to render the text and not include any .ttfs with the app.

`string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Favorites);` doesn't seem to work since `Environment.SpecialFolder` does not exist on Windows Phone.

Where are the fonts located on Windows Phone and is it possible to get a directory path to them via code?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have direct access to system folders with the Windows Phone API and you do not need it. Users cannot install any fonts, nor can the apps, so the available fonts on Windows Phone are always the same. If you want to use a custom font, you need to bundle it with your app.

Comment: I would like to use a system font but I would need a path to it. If we don't have access to these fonts, we can't read them with Freetype.